# how to resolve SSL Connect Error in curl cpp

Tags: c++, curl, https, libcurl

I have been working on an application which uses curl for communication to a server. Sometimes I get an "SSL Connect" error.

curl/libcurl version
7.86

operating system
Windows

I tried to increase verbosity on a machine where this issue is occurring, and got an "ssl handshake" error.

```
static int trace(CURL* handle, curl_infotype type, char* data, size_t size, void* userp)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case CURLINFO_TEXT:
            CLIENT_LOG_DEBUG("== Info: %s", data);
            break;
        default:
            return 0;
        case CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT:
            CLIENT_LOG_DEBUG("=> Send header: %s", data);
            break;
        case CURLINFO_DATA_OUT:
            CLIENT_LOG_DEBUG("=> Send data: %s", data);
            break;
        case CURLINFO_SSL_DATA_OUT:
            CLIENT_LOG_DEBUG("=> Send SSL data: %s", data);
            break;
        case CURLINFO_HEADER_IN:
            CLIENT_LOG_DEBUG("<= Recv header: %s", data);
            break;
        case CURLINFO_DATA_IN:
            CLIENT_LOG_DEBUG("<= Recv data: %s", data);
            break;
        case CURLINFO_SSL_DATA_IN:
            CLIENT_LOG_DEBUG("<= Recv SSL data: %s", data);
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

/// at caller method:

CLIENT_LOG_INFO("TRACE_LEVEL_HIGH");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION, trace);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_DEBUGDATA, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

/// Other curl options set while making connection:

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, payload.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, payload.size());

#ifndef PLATFORM_UNIX
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "curl-ca-bundle.crt");
#endif

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteResponseCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20L);
```

```
curl::SendRequest:314 TRACE_LEVEL_HIGH

trace:45 == Info: Connected to <URL> (<IP>) port 443 (#0)

trace:45 == Info: schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate

trace:45 == Info: ALPN: offers http/1.1

trace:45 == Info: schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed

trace:45 == Info: Closing connection 0

curl::SendRequest:387 Failed sending curl request with error:SSL connect error
```

I am only getting `CURLINFO_TEXT` logs, no header out, data out, etc.

I am stuck here. This doesn't seem to be a certificate-related issue.

Comment: `CURLOPT_DEBUGDATA` expects `void*` you pass `long`, this is undefined behavior.
`CURLOPT_VERBOSE` expects `long` you pass `int`, this is undefined behavior on non Windows platforms.

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates the TLS handshake key exchange does not finish successfully. Try to experiment with adding one of the lines below:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3 | CURL_SSLVERSION_MAX_TLSv1_2);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3 | CURL_SSLVERSION_MAX_TLSv1_1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3 | CURL_SSLVERSION_MAX_TLSv1_0);
```